# how do you copy a mysql query minus the primary key into another table

Tags: mysql

in my code I have the table itself created, I am just trying to copy all fields from one table into another

```
INSERT INTO $tbl_query (imagetargetpath, gamename, gamedirectory, like, dislike) 
 SELECT *
 FROM $sql_tbl 
WHERE gamename LIKE '%$item_searched%'
```

the table itself was created and structured like this

```
$tbl_query(`id` INT( 14 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`imagetargetpath` VARCHAR( 80 ) NOT  NULL , 
`gamename` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL , `gamedirectory` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL 
, `like` INT( 14 ) NOT NULL , `dislike` INT( 14 ) NOT NULL ,PRIMARY KEY (  `id` )) ";
```

my goal is basically to copy the query results into a new table but have the $tbl_query have its own unique id numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select only the columns you need:

```
INSERT INTO $tbl_query (imagetargetpath, gamename, gamedirectory, `like`, dislike) 
SELECT imagetargetpath, gamename, gamedirectory, `like`, dislike
FROM $sql_tbl 
WHERE gamename LIKE '%$item_searched%'
```

FYI, this problem/question comes up a lot with databases, so it worth remembering how to do it

Comment: that worked, I had a similar output for it but it didn't work that way. I think I need to learn sql better

Comment: oh.... I see where i messed up.. it was the like statement. had to focus on the code. thanks again bohemian, it worked great